# Flutter Shake Detector doesn't detect phone's shake

Tags: android, ios, flutter, shake

I'm using [Shake Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/shake) in order to detect shakes on my application, but it doesn't seem to work either on my physical device (Samsung Galaxy A71) or on my Android Emulator.

Here is how I initialise the ShakeDetector:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _hasShaked;
  ShakeDetector _shakeDetector;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _hasShaked = false;
    _shakeDetector = ShakeDetector.autoStart(
      onPhoneShake: () {
        print('shake')
        setState(() {
          _hasShaked = true;
          _shakeDetector.stopListening();
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I tried to use `ShakeDetector#waitForStart()` instead but it doesn't work either:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _hasShaked;
  ShakeDetector _shakeDetector;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _hasShaked = false;
    _shakeDetector = ShakeDetector.waitForStart(
      onPhoneShake: () {
        print('shake')
        setState(() {
          _hasShaked = true;
          _shakeDetector.stopListening();
        });
      },
    );
  _shakeDetector.startListening();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Here is my dependencies in my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  shake: ^0.1.0
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to shake very hard